# Routing Error after submitting using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, routes, submit

Whenever I press the submit button, the error reads: No route matches [POST] "/contacts/new". I just started learning Ruby on Rails and I have no clue how to solve this. Will really appreciate any help! Thanks :)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root to: 'pages#home'
 get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
 resources :contacts
end
```

Above is my route file

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @contact = Contact.new
    end
    def create
      @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
      if @contact.save
         redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
      else
         redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occured."
      end
    end
    private
      def contact_params
         params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
      end
end
```

Above is my controller file

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <h3 class="text-center">Contact us</h3>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <%= flash[:notice] %>
      <div class="well">
        <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
        
          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :comments %>
          <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And above is my view file

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :comments
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Above is my migration file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20210210035931) do

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
  end

end
```

Above is my schema.rb file. I have a question here though: according to what I learnt, I would have columns (e.g `t.string "email"` automatically generated in the schema.rb file but it appears empty in my file. Is this normal? Added the columns in manually but the Routing Error still exits.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    
end
```

Above is my Contact Model File (contact.rb)

```
Started GET "/contacts/new" for 128.106.252.65 at 2021-02-17 12:25:05 +0000
Cannot render console from 128.106.252.65! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
  Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 52.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/contacts/new" for 128.106.252.65 at 2021-02-17 12:25:08 +0000
Cannot render console from 128.106.252.65! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/contacts/new"):
  
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered collection of /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [10 times] (3.0ms)
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendering /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (27.1ms)
```

Above is the full stack trace.

[Routing Error Message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqMNf.jpg)

Comment: At what point does the error appear?

Comment: Whenever I press the submit button. I am creating a simple form where I can type things into it and once I click submit, it will be saved in a database

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Can you try `form_for Contact.new` instead of `form_for @contact` ? I wonder why `form_for @contact` is generating wrong POST path!

Comment: @SharvyAhmed I'm using rails 5.0.0. ```form_for Contact.new``` doesn't work and now I am getting a new error (NoMethodError) for this code  ```<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>```, stating "undefined method `name' for #<Contact id: nil>". Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Jiajun To be honest, I'm very confused by your errors. It would have been helpful if you shared the **full** code and error (how is your database/model defined? What is the full stack trace, not only the last line, of the error?). Nothing about your original code looks wrong to me, so I'm fairly sure the problem is *something else* that you haven't shown us.

Comment: For example, this error: `#<Contact id: nil>` implies that your model has no attributes??!! Have you added the `name`, `email` and `comments` columns to the database? Also, the fact that this is a **different** error message makes zero sense to me; is there something odd going on in your view file that you haven't shown us?

Comment: @TomLord Added in the migration, schema, model files and the full trace. Let me know if you need more info and would really appreciate if you could take a look. Also, the second error regarding ``` #<Contact id: nil>``` is solved so don't worry about that.

Comment: Your schema looks wrong; maybe you didn't run the database migration? Or maybe you edited the migration *after* running it, so need to rollback-and-rerun it? I don't know what you mean by "the error is solved", because according to what you shared above, your table has no columns.

Comment: Also, what you've shared above is **not** the full error. You said the error was `No route matches [POST] "/contacts/new"`? Well, where is that line in the error message? What you've shown us is half an error message, with the interesting line(s) missing :D

Comment: @TomLord I did run ```rails db:migrate``` to do the database migration but my schema file just doesn't match my migration file. I tried ```rails db:rollback``` and migrated again, also deleted the migration and schema files and restarted again but the same problem exist: schema doesnt match. Whats your thoughts on this?

Comment: ```No route matches [POST] "/contacts/new"
Rails.root: /home/ec2-user/environment/saasapp``` Thats the only thing my error shows. Other than that, it shows my rails routes, request and response. Where can I find more lines to my error message?

Comment: Regarding the migration, it's hard to say for sure, but your system sounds like it's in a funny state - like, maybe you *deleted the original migration file* and are therefore struggling to perform a rollback. Depending on what the overall system looks like, you might find it easier to just delete *all* migrations and start again (??!), or maybe you'd do better to just create a new migration to fix the system state.

Comment: As for that error, for the third time, I'll say: Can you show the *full* error, all together? Clearly the full error is not what you posted above, because it didn't contain the final line; and clearly your comment above is not the full error, because it doesn't contain any of the stack trace. There's almost certainly a few crucial lines directly next to the error message which show *where the error comes from*, but you still haven't shown us.

Comment: @TomLord When u say I should delete all migrations, does that mean I should delete the migration and schema files? Also, should I delete the development.splite and seeds.rb files?

Comment: Sorry I am really new to the coding world but I can't seem to find more lines to my error message. I attach a screenshot of my error on my post; hope that will help. Also, really appreciate your replies!

Comment: @Jiajun RE: Fixing the migration - my point is that your setup is clearly broken, if the migration says to add columns, and you've run the migration, and those columns don't exist. In which case, **maybe** the easiest fix (assuming your application is still super tiny) is to drop the database and start again by just creating a fresh new migration. The alternative would be to actually figure out what's gone wrong and fix it, but I find it very difficult to give more specific advice here, as I'd be much more useful sat at your screen and seeing exactly what you've done.

Comment: Regarding the error message, you see that button saying "full trace"? Click it. You can also see the full trace by reading the rails console log -- which is probably visible in a terminal right now, or at the very least you can open `log/development.log` and see the last lines.

Comment: @TomLord Updated the full stack trace on my post. Hopefully it is the correct one. Do you see any crucial lines?

Comment: Hi @TomLord Finally managed to figure it out! Added this line of code: ```post 'contacts/new', to: 'contacts#create'``` to my routes.rb file. However, I have 1 more question. I knew I needed to add this code because according to the error, my app is directing to contacts/new to execute the post action BUT in fact, my routes.rb only has the post action on contacts/. So instead of adding another route, is there a way to change my submit button's directing from contacts/new to contacts/?

Comment: I don't understand why your form is posting to that URL; that's not normal. As someone already suggested below, you could force-fix it by adding `url: contacts_path` to the form. But it seems like you *already did this*, and encountered a new error - it doesn't look like your form is submitting the expected parameters, either???!! This is really weird. What does the HTML for your form look like?

Comment: @TomLord Something really weird happened. I deleted the line of code I added to my routes.rb file and my app runs successfully. The code is still exactly the same. The only difference I observe is my schema.rb which now automatically aligns with my migration file. Do you think the schema.rb file not aligning to my migration could have caused the routing error and subsequently the parameter error (after I force-fix it)?

Comment: No, the schema does not affect the routes. The schema is a representation of the database which, in turn, will affect the model. I honestly have no idea what was going wrong here, as I don't know how to reproduce the weird behaviour you were seeing. But I'm glad to hear it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form to resource, it should be submitted to `[POST] /contacts/` not `[POST] /contacts/new` as stated in the error.

You should update your form to submit to the correct path.

Tip: Use `rails routes` command in terminal to view all routes in your application.

Comment: How do I update my form's submit to the correct path? Like where do I change it? Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: A quick way is updating form in the view file
``<%= form_for @contact, url: contacts_path do |f| %>`` 
I just directed it to the correct url instead of the wrong one.

Comment: Also please mention the tutorial you are following. That would be helpful for anyone trying to help.
I would recommend following the [official one](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/getting_started.html)

Comment: I am following the Essential Web Developer Course on this website: https://upskillcourses.com/courses

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt work hahaha. It gives me a new error ```ActionController::ParameterMissing in ContactsController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: contact```

Comment: Can you show me the stack trace, because if this error is raised inside the controller means that it is routed correctly and there are some missing required fields in the form

Comment: Hey, something really weird happened lol. Could you read my comment above?

Comment: I read it. Actually, that seems the normal that should be the result of your code in the question. What happened with you before is weird and I can't understand why it happened.